# Facing the null injector error while trying to perform end to end testing for data service using Jasmine

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework

**Facing the null injector error while trying to perform end to end testing for data service using Jasmine.**

NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[DatabaseService -> AngularFirestore -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options!

if I run 'ng test' always shows this error

```
DatabaseService > should be created
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[DatabaseService -> AngularFirestore -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options!
error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ 'DatabaseService', 'AngularFirestore', 'InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options', 'InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options' ] })
    at <Jasmine>
    at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:915:1)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:11082:1)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:11082:1)
    at injectInjectorOnly (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:801:1)
    at ɵɵinject (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:805:1)
    at Object.AngularFirestore_Factory [as factory] (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/fire/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/angular-fire-firestore.js:869:149)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:11249:1)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:11071:1)
    at injectInjectorOnly (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:801:1)
    at ɵɵinject (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:805:1)
Expected undefined to be truthy.
Error: Expected undefined to be truthy.
    at <Jasmine>
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/app/shared/database/database.service.spec.ts:14:21)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:364:1)
```

here is my **database.service.spec.ts**

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { DatabaseService } from './database.service';

describe('DatabaseService', () => {
  let service: DatabaseService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
    service = TestBed.inject(DatabaseService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

**database.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
// firebase
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment.prod';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DatabaseService {
  public frb: any = firebase;
  public allCollections = {
    users: 'users',
  };
  constructor(
    public afs: AngularFirestore,
  ) {}
  // create
  addDocument(collection:string, docObject:any){
    return this.afs.collection(collection).add(docObject);
  }
}
```

here all angularfire module in **app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from "@angular/router";
import { PathLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from "@angular/common";

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from "@ionic/angular";
import { SplashScreen } from "@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx";
import { StatusBar } from "@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx";

import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
// firebase
import { AngularFireModule } from "@angular/fire";
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from "@angular/fire/auth";
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from "@angular/fire/database";
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from "@angular/fire/firestore";
import { AngularFirestore } from "@angular/fire/firestore";
import { environment } from "../environments/environment";
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

// ion2-calendar
import { CalendarModule } from "ion2-calendar";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFirestore,
    CalendarModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "****",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.0",
    "@capacitor/android": "^2.4.5",
    "@capacitor/core": "2.4.5",
    "@codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth": "^2.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/pwa-elements": "^3.0.2",
    "firebase": "^8.2.7",
    "firebaseui": "^4.7.1",
    "ion2-calendar": "^3.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "talisman": "^1.1.4",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.0.0",
    "@capacitor/cli": "2.4.5",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is a bit specific

> No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2

Angular fire is missing from your imports

```typescript
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
```

I have not used AngularFire but from the error you need to import `AngularFireModule`. Try below

```typescript
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFirestore,
  });
```

Comment: Thank you Owen Kelvin, tried your suggestion. Still facing the same issue. Any other suggestion is much appreciated.